# How do I replace cell values from column A to column B in Excel 2012?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to find all cell values in column 'A' with, let's say a value "gmail.com" and replace all values of column B with "EN" (change the value in the same row of A and B result).

Is there a function that does this?

Answer (score 2):

- insert a blank column in column C
- in `C1` put `=IF(A1="gmail.com","EN",B1)` and copy down
- copy and paste special value column C over the values in Column B
- delete the working column C

For a partial search try something like
`=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("gmail.com",A1)>0),B1,"EN")` in `C1`
then copy down etc

Comment: I did that but it said the formula contains an error. I have about 7000 rows in the excel is there any faster way, then copying?

Comment: You could use code but you will probably find a formula more adaptable without additional help. Can you provide a snapshot of you data higlighting where the formula is not working?

Comment: Here's a screenshot (http://i48.tinypic.com/2s0efxw.jpg). First I just tested this formula for one value but it warned me with an error. I forgot to mention earlier that searching value should contain not match exact. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use an `IF` statement combined with a `RIGHT` function in column B. Place this formula in `B1`.

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,9)="gmail.com","EN", "HR")
```

This will look for the `gmail.com` and if it exists will populate the cell with `EN`, otherwise it will make it `HR`.

To copy it down all the rows in the column, double click on the bottom right corner of the cell where the drag cross is.

Comment: If you want to do this multiple times, do `=IF(RIGHT(A1,9)="gmail.com", "EN", IF(RIGHT(A1,7)="msn.com", "MC", "HR"))`. You can unlimitedly nest this IF structure, but it will quickly get confusing

Answer (score -1):

Use `Sort & Filter`.

Select column A and B (entirely) and apply the (auto)filter; select filter options on column A and chose text filters: contains. Set contains to "gmail.com", and apply filter. Column B will be filtered accordingly.

Change the first cell in column B, and copy it (<kbd>Ctrl C</kbd>). Then select the remaining cells in column B and press <kbd>Ctrl V</kbd>.

Comment: They don't want to replace `gmail.com` in column A. They want to replace the value in column B based on `gmail.com` existing in column A.